# Expected 'id' default mouse to be mapped to InputState whose subtype is undefined, got: pointerMove

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have searched Stackoverflow for this one and I have found a previous post, but had no help as the code suggested was in C

```
        WebElement termsElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='terms']"));
        WebElement marketingElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='allowMarketing']"));
        System.out.println(termsElement.isDisplayed() + " & " +  marketingElement.isDisplayed());
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(termsElement).click().perform();
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(marketingElement).click().perform();
```

This throws the pointer exception in the title.
I've tried element.click(); yet it didn't action anything, so I've had to resort to using Actions to direct the mouse.

The System.out.println prints 'true & true', so the elements are visible and in view

Relevant DOM

```
<div class="checkbox small">
<input id="terms" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" name="terms" ng-model="checkout.TandCsAccepted" ng-click="ClickTsAndCs()" type="checkbox">
<label for="terms">
</div>
<h4 class="margin--top-2x">E-mail Marketing Preferences</h4>
<p></p>
<div class="checkbox small">
<input id="allowMarketing" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="" name="allowMarketing" ng-model="checkout.AllowMarketing" type="checkbox">
<label for="allowMarketing"> I would like to receive emails, newsletters and offers </label>
</div>
```

Why is this exception being thrown? And how do I avoid it? I'm trying to make it tick both the inputs boxes. inputelement.click(); doesnt work for some odd reason. This works completely fine on Chrome, just not on Firefox

Comment: What are your exact steps you want to perform? Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: Why deal with actions? Why not just `termsElement.click()` and `marketingElement.click()`? Edit - just saw your update. My guess is you want to click the input, and not the label, or the div even

Comment: @mrfreester This doesn't work for some odd reason, it doesn't throw an exception, it just doesn't do anything.  and yes to your edit.

Comment: @Dev I have edited the question with DOM and more information. Thanks

Comment: Try this `xpath`, and get rid of the actions: `//label[@for='terms']/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'checkbox')]` or `//label[@for='terms']/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'checkbox')]/input` and let me know what happens

Comment: @mrfreester Getting element not visible from that, which I what I got from .click()

Comment: @JordanBenyon did you get `ElementNotVisible` from both of those? One grabs the `div`, the other grabs the `input`.

Comment: @mrfreester ElementNotVisible only on the Input. but clicking anywhere else using .click(); doesn't actually do anything, using .movetoelement().perform(); throws the error in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        WebElement termsElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='terms']"));
        WebElement marketingElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='allowMarketing']"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("payforitems")));
        int getpoint = ((termsElement.getSize().width)/2) -1;
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(termsElement, getpoint ,0).click()
                           .moveToElement(marketingElement, getpoint ,0).click()
                           .build()
                           .perform();
                           sleep(1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("payforitems")).click();
```

For anybody that finds this after.

The problem lay with the fact that Firefox has an issue dealing with Actions, a certain version of firefox driver fails after the first Action is called (it was called in another test method previously) when I removed that, and reworked the code to not used actions, I made one new Actions call and put all the actions into that and performed it, it just means I cannot use any more actions later.

The reason I am declaring the width of the element and clicking towards the side of the label is because in the middle is a href link which it will click instead. So I'm directing the click away from that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code for you to try:

```
    WebElement termsElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='terms']"));
    WebElement marketingElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='allowMarketing']"));
    System.out.println(termsElement.isDisplayed() + " & " +  marketingElement.isDisplayed());
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(termsElement).click().build().perform();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(marketingElement).click().build().perform();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Throws ElementNotVisible. To clarify, this is the only element with that id.

Comment: yeah, returned 'true & true', even did getElements and print the Size of the List, and it returns 1 on both.

Comment: check with my updated code & let me know the status.

Comment: Nopes, you were trying to click on the label which you shouldn't. Rather you should try to click on the check-box. There's a difference. My aim is to suggest you simple tweaks to your own program. I don't code rocket science :)

Comment: My apologies, the code doesn't throw an error, yet it carry on like its done it. yet the tick boxes dont enable. Pressing the label should also tick the box as designed from the developers.

Comment: Added some implicitly wait to my to my code, try my updated code.

Comment: This is now returning false false. the two inputs don't seem to be classed as visible/displayed, yet you can see them on the website. Even with the implicit wait, I'm still getting the original exception. 

Expected 'id' default mouse to be mapped to InputState whose subtype is undefined, got: pointerMove

Comment: If clicking the `label` also checks the box, then you probably need to click the `div`, or even some other container